# willTurnIntoFault being called more than once, resulting in crash

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsundomanager, key-value-observing

In a subclass of `NSManagedObject` my overridden implementation of `willTurnIntoFault` is being called twice when undoing some code which originally created the object in question.  This results in a crash when attempting to double-unregister for KVO on a key path.

The Apple documents say this is the right place to un-register for KVO.

A bit of context - the undo operation involves removing the corresponding view of the model from it's superview.  The view retains it's model.

So my question is: **what kind of programmer errors can result in `willTurnIntoFault` being called twice in a subclass of `NSManagedObject`?**

Note: Previously I was overriding `dealloc` in this class but have since realised this is not recommended for subclasses of NSManagedObject.  I've since moved this code into `-didTurnIntoFault`.  I'm not currently overriding any other methods which the Apple docs say you should not override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was caused by a custom setter method which was setting/unsetting KVO values from within willTurnIntoFault.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity's sake: I had the same problem. In my case I had an object *A* with a (to-one) relation to an object *B*. When *A* got deleted *B*'s inverse relation to *A* was set to `null`. This caused *B*'s `observeValueOfKeyPath:ofObject:change:context` method to be invoked (where `keypath` was *B*'s relation to *A*). Unfortunately this method checked a property of *A*, causing the faulting of *A* to be cancelled (note that in this situation `awakeFromFetch` does not get called--I presume because the object never actually did get to fault state). Hence I might might get a second call to `willTurnIntoFault` later and the object would try to unregister for KVO again, resulting in a crash--just like in the OP.

For me the solution was to change the delete rule for A to cascade, so that the B object got deleted when the A object got deleted **AND** to unregister for KVO in `prepareForDeletion`. This is important because the deletion of *A* will still cause *B*'s inverse relation to be set to nil before *B* is actually deleted.

Note that `prepareForDeletion` gets called before **but not instead** of `willTurnIntoFault`. Hence, if you unregister for KVO in both, you need to maintain some state to make sure you have not already unregistered.

Comment: Good observation (albeit from the School of Hard Knocks).